# Cannot authenticate to SBS 2003

Tags: 12.04, networking, authentication

I am trying to connect my machine to my work's entirely windows network and I am having a few issues:

- Whenever I try to access the server, the authentication dialog just keeps popping back up.
- I cannot connect to the printers (it says connecting to device failed)

I have tried setting up samba, winbind, kerberos, likewise open all to no avail. I have a feeling I am just setting them up wrong.

My nautilus shows this when I go to Network > Windows Network > MASTERMAGNETS

[image]

I can ping both MASTERMAGNETS.LOCAL and 192.168.0.2 after modifying my `/etc/hosts`

```
james@jamesmaddison:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost jamesmaddison
192.168.0.2 MASTERMAGNETS.LOCAL
192.168.0.50 Sharp-Printer

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I believe that's the correct domain (not sure if that's the correct term) as when I do `nslookup MASTERMAGNETS.LOCAL` I get the following:

```
james@jamesmaddison:~$ nslookup MASTERMAGNETS.LOCAL
Server:     192.168.0.2
Address:    192.168.0.2#53

Name:   MASTERMAGNETS.LOCAL
Address: 192.168.0.3
Name:   MASTERMAGNETS.LOCAL
Address: 192.168.0.2
```

It all worked fine before I reinstalled Ubuntu and now I just cannot get access to the server.

All help is appreciated, I need to get this working or I fear I will be forced to develop in a windows environment :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the network admin delete my account and remake it and that seemed to work now.

I don't know whether Kerberos automatically synced or anything after that but it worked!